# Vertical document points-of-interest highlighter component of an IDE. What's it called?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, ide

Both Eclipse an Netbeans provide a vertical points of interest highlighter next to document scroll bars, which appears to be a part of an extended `JScrollPane` or is simply a standalone custom component.

I've marked it on the picture below (Netbeans and Eclipse version, in that order).

[image: Bookmark Gutter]

It highlights lots of different things and represents a flat view of the entire document.

What is this area/component called in general?

I've been looking around on pointers on how to implement such a thing in swing or abuse an existing implementation to my liking but I don't even know what to search for. Both implementations of this thing appear to be quite similar, so I'm hoping they are based on the same piece of code.

Comment: please Q: do you want to paint only tracks or mouse_events will scroll to this Point, both are few times asked and solved here

Comment: @mKorbel: both, I'd appreciate links to those. While I was not specifically asking about an actual implementation, others that stumble upon my question might be interested about them.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600605/714968) by @aterai, this is 1st that I can search here, leaveing advanced searching (tag == JScrollBar)

Answer (score 2):

It's an extend `JScrollPane` which has implemted some kind of column footer.

The default `JScrollPane` provides row and column headers by default, check out [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Try taking a look at [`JideScrollPane`](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/JideScrollPane.html) from [jidesoft](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm)

Comment: This tutorial was the first stop for me when I started the search. I somehow managed to miss the header views. The component I'm looking for would probably be named "column header view".

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be call bookmarks for all we know.  It's placed within the column footer of the custom scrollpane...but they are called is another thing...

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse just calls these `vertical rulers` (they are implemented with `SWT` in Eclipse).

Comment: This was useful. I managed to find a Netbeans platform equivalent based on it. I believe they named it "Error Stripe" though it represents much more than just errors.